# Add a number in list so it becomes 20 percent

Tags: c#, itext, percentage

I want to add a number in a list of numbers so that after adding this number in that list, it is 20 percent of whole list.

The goal is to set width of first column absolute (20%) and relative for others columns while creating table in itextsharp PDF.

For example here is a list {10,30,20,20}. What should I add in it which is also 20% of whole sum of list, which is 20 ( 20+10+30+20+20 = 100, 20/100 -> 20%).

Comment: Show the failing code so that we can tell you how you're doing it wrong.

Comment: The question is not clear enough, It would be great if you add the current code, or how the list looks like and how it will be after the operations

Comment: there is no code yet, i am unable to even create any kind of equation @user3185569

Comment: @Charlie At least show an example list and the expected result !

Comment: I only see one iText-related answer...

Comment: So you already knew that for a sum of 80 you needed a value or 20...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some basic math like 0.20 = x / (Sum + x) give you x = Sum/4. So `Enumerable.Sum` will give you most of the result:

```
listOfInt.Add (listOfInt.Sum()/4);
```

Comment: Answer is accurate and simple :) Please explain little bit more. Thankyou so much

Answer (score 0):

So what I'm understanding is you want the width of column 1 to be 20% the width of all columns.  You will need to add up all the columns:

```
TOTAL_WIDTH = COL1 + COL2 + COL3 + ...
COL1 = 0.2 * TOTAL_WIDTH

COL1 = 0.2 (COL1 + COL2 + COL3 + ...)
COL1 - 0.2 * COL1 = 0.2 * (COL2 + COL3 + ...)
0.8 * COL1 = 0.2 * (COL2 + COL3 + ...)
COL1 = 0.25 * (COL2 + COL3 + ...)
```

Comment: But what COL1 do you use in your first calculation?

Comment: If you do the algebra you will get:

col1 = 0.2 * col1 + 0.2 * (col2 + col3 +...),
0.8 * col1 = 0.2 * (col2 + col3 + ...),
col1 = 0.25 * (col2 + col3 + ...)

Comment: Now that is more useful. The first 2 lines are just what Charlie posted and they alone didn't help at all. :P

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to do:

```
N4 = TOTAL * 0.2   
N1 + N2 + N3 + TOTAL * 0.2 = TOTAL
N1 + N2 + N3 = TOTAL * 0.8
(N1 + N2 + N3) / 0.8 = TOTAL
```

So...

```
N4 = ((N1 + N2 + N3) / 0.8) * 0.2
N4 = (N1 + N2 + N3) / 4
```

So make this num the 25% of the sum of the others and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

The first part of your question is strange: you talk of a list and it's as if you want the first item to take 20% of the complete list. You should add a drawing to help us understand what that would mean.

The second part of your question talks about a table. That's easy. If you look in the official documentation, you'll find the answer to the question [How to change width of single column of table?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-change-width-single-column-table)

You can set the relative width using the `setWidths()` method. In your case, you'd have:

```
int columns = 8;
float[] widths = new float[columns];
float[0] = 20f;
for (int i = 1; i < columns; i++)
    float[i] = 80 / (columns - 1);
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(columns);
table.setWidths(widths);
```

Change `8` into any number you want if you need more or less than 8 columns.

**Update:**

In the meantime, you have clarified your question.

Suppose that you have a `float[]` named `widths1` that contains widths of a table. Note that you will need `float` instead of `int` because we are going to make divisions.

In that case, you can do this:

```
int n = widths1.length;
float total = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    total += widths1[i];
n++;
float[] widths2 = new float[n];
widths2[0] = total / 4;
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    widths2[i] = widths1[i - 1];
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(n);
table.setWidths(widths2);
```